# How do I get multiple scanf or getchar prompts in C?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to write a C program, but for some reason I can't use more than one scanf or getchar prompt. I want it to look something like this:

```
"Please enter the first number:"
[user enters number]
"Please enter the second number:"
[user enters number]
```

But currently, it skips the second prompt. I'm using a simple

> scanf("%d", first),

and

> scanf("%d", second).

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try showing us the relevant portion of your code.  We're not mind readers.

Comment: Please add your code,Without it the answers will be just speculation.

Answer (score 1):

You should clean the buffer after the first scanf(), using fflush (stdin). Or you could use getchar().

You can find further explanations here: http://www.phanderson.com/C/scanf.html

Comment: fflush will flush the ENTIRE input buffer, which might flush more than you want -- if there are multiple lines that have already been read, it will flush all of them.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you input the first value at the command line, you actually put 2 characters in the stdin buffer, the character you want and the LF character.

It is generally accepted that you are better off using fgets(char *s, int n, FILE *stream), where *stream is stdin, *s is a char array, and n is the maximum number of characters to read. This gives you more control over the number of bytes read in to prevent overflow errors. In this case it is 2 because it is the character you want plus the LF character. Strings in C are null terminated so you will need at least a 3 byte array to hold one character. To access the one character you want, just read from the the 0 index of the array you passed to fgets.

Ex:

```
char buffer[3];
fgets(buffer,2,stdin);
charyouwant = buffer[0];
```